# LARAVEL column Eloquent query with OrderByRaw

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I need to calculate distance with latitude,longitude and order it by nearest,

but in my OrderBy clause latitude is missing, I don't know why

```
  ->with(['foglio' => function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude) {
    $query->select([
      'id',
      'indirizzo',
      'piano',
      'categoria',
      'consistenza',
      'latitude',
      'longitude',
    ]);
    $query->WhereNotNull(['indirizzo', 'latitude', 'longitude']);
  }])
  ->limit($limit)
  ->orderBy(DB::raw('ABS(latitude - ' . $latitude . ') + ABS(longitude - ' . $longitude . ')'), 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

->orderByRaw('ABS(latitude - ' . $latitude . ') + ABS(longitude - ' . $longitude . ') ASC')

Comment: unknow latitude column

Answer (score 0):

> You should use **left join**, not **eager loading**.
>   Eager loading will produce two seperate queries and that's why you can't access latitude
>   column in order by clause.